# Can't get Reactable for React Native working, due to "Invariant Violation: View config not found for name input"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have tried following [this tutorial](https://www.davidmeents.com/creating-tables-with-react-that-you-can-sort-filter-and-customize/) to try and get a reactable table working in my React Native app, and I am running into constant errors along the lines of `Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: View config not found for name th`. I tried just running the [source code](https://gist.github.com/dmeents/9b8b0c6cad3a6564df5d02e6000d6860#file-reactable-tutorial-js) for the tutorial, but I keep getting `Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: View config not found for name input`.

What gives? Is it simply not possible to use Reactable with React Native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can't user DOM elements in React Native. That library is for React, not React Native (at least there is no indication in their documentations). Use this one instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-table-component